# subscribe to response from one service in other

Tags: angular

I have two components in one window. First is a calendar, by clicking on OK button it sends some data to service. Service via post request get some response.
I need to display that result of the response immediately in another component. I think, that I need to make a shared service for that, but how should I do it?
How so subscribe to response in shared service, cause it wants the arguments?

service:

```
 getData(model:any): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/schedule",JSON.stringify(model))
      .map((response:Response)=>{
        this.schedule = response.json();
        return response.json();  
      });
  }
```

calendar.component:

```
  getData(){
    this.http.getData({id_teacher: this.id,date: this.model.formatted}).subscribe(result => {
      this.data = result;
      // console.log(this.data)
    });
    // console.log(this.http.schedule);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here all you need is `Subject` :

Just follow the `// Execution flow` in below code and you'll be clear about the flow also.

**service :**

```
public scheduleData : Subject<any> = new Subject<any>(); // create a Observable Subject 

getData(model:any): Observable<any>{ // Execution flow 2
    return this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/schedule",JSON.stringify(model))
        .map((response:Response)=>{
            this.scheduleData.next(response.json()); // This will emit event asap change // Execution flow 3
        });
}
```

**calendar.component.ts :**

```
// just call this from component 1
this.http.getData({id_teacher: this.id,date: this.model.formatted}).subscribe(); // Execution flow 1
```

**calendar2.component.ts :**

```
// component 2 : this will be called asap any changes in scheduleData
// Execution flow 4
this.http.scheduleData.subscribe(result => 
    this.data = result; // Execution flow 5
    // console.log(this.data)
});
```

> **And Service must be shared b/w these 2 components**

Comment: Yeah, I almost got it. However, how in calendar2.component that function should be called?

Comment: @ДамирСаматов , nope all you need is to just subscribe to it.

Comment: I know, I'm doing smth wrong)   export class ResultsComponent implements OnChanges {
  data: any;
  constructor(private http:RequestService) { }
  
  ngOnChanges() 
  {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
    this.http.scheduleData.subscribe(result => {
      this.data = result;
    });
    console.log(this.data);
  }
  }

Comment: @ДамирСаматов , Correct , your `console.log(this.data); ` should be within `subscribe` function .

Comment: But nothing happens

Comment: @ДамирСаматов , it must work , There might be some other issue , creat a working demo on stackblitz , That would be easy to debug.

Comment: It's not working,just to show u code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rmtbx Is that really should be written as function in my second comonent and initialised in ngOnInit

Comment: @ДамирСаматов , please solve other errors first , its showing `hello.component.ts` not found

Comment: @ДамирСаматов , Glad to know , sorry was my mistake please check now , it will work with subject also `this.scheduleData.next(response.json());` , Happy Coding BTW :)